# How to import from a subdirectory in a nodejs typescript package?

Tags: node.js, typescript, package

Let us assume a npm package with the following files:

```
./index.ts
./controller/index.ts
./controller/my-controller.ts
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"],
  "paths": {
      "my-package": ["./src/index"],
      "my-package/controller": ["./src/controller/index"]
  }
}
```

The index.ts file in controller is exporting my-controller. What I want to do now is to import MyController like this:

`import {MyController} from 'my-package/controller';`

but I got the message: `Cannot find module 'my-package/controller' or its corresponding type declarations.`. Importing from ./index.ts in root directory works without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last comment of this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079 it is mentioned to change "moduleResolution" to "Node16" in tsconfig.json. After changing it works fine for me.